# center align icons in titanium action bar for android

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

Is there any possible way to center align the action item icons that are shown in action bar of titanium app for android. I have searched a lot of places for this solution but had no luck. I want the action bar to look like the below image. Also tell me the way to not show app title in the action bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Titanium issue.
As you can read [in Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), you won't be able to center anything in the ActionBar. Default (and expected) behaviour is to align action icons on the right (or left if reversed).

I don't recommend it, as it goes against Google's guidelines, but you will be able to center icons if you create a **fake ActionBar**:
- Remove native ActionBar from any `window` in your app
- Create a Titanium `View` that mimics the ActionBar
- Add icons and bind click events.

That's it, you are done.

Comment: I am not saying that it's an issue in titanium. It's just that I have to achieve the design where icons are center aligned.

Comment: I understand. Android simply can't do that. Titanium can only do it if you use a fake ActionBar. Let me know if you need more info.